# Voice glitch while selecting signal to play from a series incoming recorded signals

Tags: audio, digital-communications, speech-processing, audio-processing, speech

In my setting, I have multiple microphones recording the same speech signal in real-time.

The speaker is moving while speaking.

I am selecting one of the recorded signal to play based on their RMS strength (signal with greater RMS strength will be played.)

My problem arises when I know that I have to switch to other microphone signal. There is a transition time during switching and in that time I am forced to play the signal with lower RMS strength, so there appears a glitch in the played signal as during the transition time. I am playing the signal with lower RMS strength and as I shift to signal with highest RMS strength, the difference of voice amplitude produces a glitch effect.

How can I smoothen/compensate this effect?

Comment: Have you tried (cross)fading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fade_(audio_engineering) ?

Comment: Yes I did. But that also amplifies the noise. Is there any method that just strengthens the speech?

Comment: What type noise you have there to deal with? Are you constructing the final 'tape' in some audio editing software (which one) or are you doing it all in real time while speaker does his/her show? If those mics are not too far away from each other (not much delay issues present) you could mix them all, use various filters to remove unwanted noise and finally normalize or compress the outgoing audio.